# iPhone selected tabbar item Image overlay resizable image does not cover the selected tab completely

Tags: objective-c, uitabbar

I want to use a 1x1 px stretchable image on tabbar selected tab.I am using this code.

```
UIImage *selectedBgImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"active-overlay.png"];
[[UITabBar appearance]setSelectionIndicatorImage:[selectedBgImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,0, 10, 10) resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeStretch]];
```

problem is this does not cover the selected tab completely. always leave some space like 2-3 px from top.[this looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQOtU.png)

can anyone please help me in solving this problem.

Comment: Thanks @dstudeba i am new to stakOverflow so not much familiar with all editing and all...

Comment: No Problem, it would also help if you explained a little more what you wanted your tab bar to actually look like.  I take it the light blue box on the selected tab you want to go all the way to the top and bottom?

Comment: i want to cover this white overlay completely from top and bottom on selected Tab.

Comment: Check out these links they should help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10035302/uitabbar-selectionindicatorimage-padding  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23952693/wrong-size-setselectionindicatorimage

Comment: This link explaining very similar issue solution. but here i am not able to understand what size and color i should give and where i should call this class function.   can you please explain me this in steps . a big thanks to u

Comment: I tried to solve this using this link  after  creating a category of UITabbar  and adding that function http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10035302/uitabbar-selectionindicatorimage-padding    but no success yet.... can anyone help me in solving this issue...